# Chrome Extension deploy through installer - IS NO PROMPT POSSIBLE?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome-extension, wix

I have an extension which is installed via a Windows Installer (WiX) (no chrome store involved). I install it allright by adding some HKLM keys in the registry inside the Google\Chrome\Extensions... path. However, the first time Chrome is started, after the install, the user is prompted with a dialog in the upper right part of the window in order to Activate the extension. **Is there any flag or registry key I can directly modify through the installer so the extension is installed silently** without the user being asked for permission?

The dialog text says : "*another program on your computer added an extension that may change the way chrome works . It can : read an modify all your data on the websites you visit*".

Comment: I doubt it, this sounds horribly dangerous which is precisely why Chrome is preventing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional and is part of the Chrome security model.

From [the blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/12/no-more-silent-extension-installs.html):

> Extensions installed by third party programs using external extension deployment options will be disabled by default. When a third party program installs an extension, the Chrome menu will be badged, and users can click through the Chrome menu to see a dialog containing an option to enable the extension or to remove it from their computer.